# How to disable page scrolling when scrolling on a DIV element and enable scrolling when a counter reaches a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to prevent page scroll on a DIV element

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stop-scroll').on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { 

      var e0 = e.originalEvent;
      var delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

      this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
      e.preventDefault();  

    });
});
</script>
```

But I want to enable scrolling again if a counter reaches to a certain value say 4, the counter will keep increase by 1 on mouse scroll. And the counter will decrease by 1 if mouse scroll up and when the counter reaches 0 the scroll disable will be enabled again and the user can scroll the page up.

Comment: `if(++counter < x) { e.preventDefault(); }` ?!

Comment: How to capture the mouse scroll up or down to increase or decrease the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your problem I have added up a code which for now based on a particular value of a particular variable enables the scrolling.

Same way you can also use condition of your choice and implement the same logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#stop-scroll').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var e0 = e.originalEvent;
    var delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

    this.scrollTop += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;

    if (delta <= -240) {
      return true;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#stop-scroll {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #6a6a6a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stop-scroll"></div>
```

Hope so the attached code helps you understand. 
*If still, you feel any doubt feel free to comment.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css rule [`overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to control the scrolling behaviour of HTML elements.
In the example below I am using the rule [`overflow-y`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) to control the scrolling behavior of the element in the Y direction. Assigning it the value of `auto` allows the browser to decide on its own if it thinks the container needs to have a scrollbar.

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container" style="height: 50px; background-color: orangered;">
  <li>This</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>will</li>
  <li>need</li>
  <li>scrolling!</li>
</ul>

<ul class="container" style="height: 100px; background-color: skyblue;">
  <li>This</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>won't</li>
  <li>need</li>
  <li>scrolling!</li>
</ul>
```